# Javascript keeps reloading page

Tags: javascript

I have the following script which reloads the page so I can grab the latitude and longitude variables. I'd like it to reload once, however, the page continues to refresh over and over again. I can't seem to figure out why. Any insight would be very helpful.

Please find my code below:

```
window.onload = function getLocation () {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition (position) {
    window.location='location.php?  lat='+position.coords.latitude+'&long='+position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Comment: Is this script also on the page that location.php generates?

Comment: to echo @jskulski, if this script is on that page, you will get a loop.

Comment: If the script is also in location.php file, then there is a chance that window.onload and showPosition are invoked one after the other and refreshing the page continuously

Comment: You shouldn't even reload the page once.. It's an awful user experience..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never check whether the `lat` and `long` parameters are set, so you keep refreshing. To avoid this, you can check these serverside:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['lat']) && isset($_GET['long'])){
?>
    <h1>I know where you are!</h1>
<?php
    } else {
?>
    <script>
        /* Your JS script */
    </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't want to reload the page if the params are already there. To do that, add an if clause to your showPosition function:

```
function showPosition(position) 
{
  if(locationSet()) {
    window.location='location.php?  lat='+position.coords.latitude+'&long='+position.coords.longitude;
  }
}
function locationSet() {
  // TODO write function that parses window.location.search
  // for lat & long params & returns true if both set
}
```